# router suggestions

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, router

Any suggestions on buying a good router for my macbook?? I currently have a trendnet router. the wifi(WPA security) keeps dropping on a regular basis.
i am contemplating buying a apple airport extreme...but it costs 179$ ..is it worth the money???

Comment: Shopping or buying recommendation questions are considered off-topic, as reported by the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Apple [AirPort Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/) for $100 on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015YJOK2). It's a nice router, with some nifty bonus features like music streaming.

Answer (score 1):

The Extreme is an expensive router.  But my experience of it is that once set up correctly, it performs flawlessly until the day it dies (several years).  On the flip side, you may go through several $80 routers in the mean time instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're going to use all the features available from the Airport Extreme then it's probably not the best value for money.  You could buy a cheap router which is supported by one of the open source firmware versions which would allow you to 'flash' the firmware and therefore enable options which are normally only available on more expensive products.

Take a look at the following three open-source firmware pages for supported routers and have a read about what features they offer and compare to what you need.

[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)

[Openwrt](http://openwrt.org/)

[Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato)

Answer (score 0):

Our host, Jeff Atwood, wrote about that [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/because-everyone-needs-a-router.html).  I went with the Buffalo one; the stock DD-WRT-based firmware is nice as-is.